# Windows 7 over Windows 8/8.1 in Enterprise

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-8, migration

Due to microsoft announcing EOS for Win XP, big companies are trying to shift to Win 7. 
My question is why are they not shifting to Win 8?

Is it because Win 7 is tried and tested? is it because of the annoying UI of Win8? or because microsoft wants you to upgrade to Win 7 so that they can sell you Win 8 after EOL of Win 7.

Comment: My users would be ticked, they told me so. Especially after having gotten Win8 computers for Christmas. The ones with Pads otoh tend to like it in its native environment.

Answer (score 1):

It's both A and B, because Win 7 has been around a while and is stable, as well as because the UI in Win 7 is a much easier transition for people who are accustomed to XP and previous versions. The whole "Metro" UI thing, where Win 8 is half tablet half desktop, would be very counter-productive for businesses. Granted that, aside from the the Metro Start Page and lack of a true "start menu" like the previous versions had, and a couple other things (like the removal of Aero and making everything flat and boxy looking), it's pretty much the same as Win 7. But it would still be too much of a shock, especially to old Win XP users, if the companies went straight to Win 8. They would lose a huge amount of productivity because employees would have to re-learn all their old Win XP habits. They would have to hire people to teach seminars on how to use the new windows, and then spend the money to organize those seminars, etc. It's just too much of a business risk.

Some companies may upgrade to Win 8 eventually (maybe in a year or two), unless Microsoft decides to release Windows 9 as a desktop only version, and make a separate version for tablets, instead of this hybrid thing they did with Win 8.

Personally I think it was a bad decision on Microsoft's part to try to hybridize tablets and desktops, but it is what it is. That being said, I'm sticking with Windows 8 (still not sure about upgrading to 8.1 though) because it's just easier to adapt than try to cling to old things, and it actually does perform faster and more efficiently (at least on the technical side of things). The boot-up, shutdown, restart, and standby/resume times are astonishing.